# CAShapeLayer Animation without having to update the path

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation, catransaction

When animating a CAShapeLayer, is it necessary to constantly keep updating the path of the layer, or is there a way to rely on CABasicAnimation alone?

In the example below, I set up four circles paths and draw them.
Then I want to animate them down to disappear. After the animation has completed however, they spring back to their original paths.

```
    int radius =  halfWidth-30; //the radius is the distance out from the centre
    trackActive.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:cicleCenter radius:radius startAngle:degreesToRadians(circleStart) endAngle:degreesToRadians(circleEnd) clockwise:true].CGPath;
    circleActive.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:cicleCenter radius:radius startAngle:degreesToRadians(circleStart) endAngle:degreesToRadians(circleEnd) clockwise:true].CGPath;

    radius = halfWidth - 10;
    trackNew.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:cicleCenter radius:radius startAngle:degreesToRadians(circleStart) endAngle:degreesToRadians(circleEnd) clockwise:true].CGPath;
    circleNew.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:cicleCenter radius:radius startAngle:degreesToRadians(circleStart) endAngle:degreesToRadians(circleEnd) clockwise:true].CGPath;

    NSArray * layers = @[trackActive, circleActive, trackNew, circleNew];
    for (CAShapeLayer * layer in layers){

        [CATransaction begin];
        CABasicAnimation * animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
        animation.duration = 1.0f;
        animation.removedOnCompletion = false;
        animation.fromValue = @(1.0);
        animation.toValue = @(0.0);
        animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"circleAnimation"];

        [CATransaction commit];
    }
```

I understand that I can add this to set the new path:

```
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{

        //set the new path
        layer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:cicleCenter radius:radius startAngle:degreesToRadians(circleStart) endAngle:degreesToRadians(arcEnd) clockwise:true].CGPath;

    }];
```

But would prefer avoid keep having to update the path, and instead rely on the animation layer exclusively. Is this possible?

Something like: layer.path = animation.path or animation.updatesOriginalPath=true; could be wishful thinking, not sure.

Comment: You can omit the spring back effect by setting strokeEnd of the layer to zero, because the animation doesn't modify the layer's state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code and omit the spring effect:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
layer.strokeEnd = 0.0;
[CATransaction commit];
```

The transaction will create and add an implicit animation object for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a flag in a an animation so it stays where it was in the end and starts where it should start like this:

```
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
```

check also this answer:
[What exactly does removedOnCompletion = NO do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747248/what-exactly-does-removedoncompletion-no-do)

Comment: You should avoid keeping animations on layers. Removing or replacing the animation later will lead to _unexpected_ effects. A `layer.strokeEnd = 0.0` before `addAnimation` will have the same effect.

Comment: Another disadvantage of keeping the animation is that the layer doesn't reflects it's _visible state_. It returns always 1.0 for `strokeEnd` but it displays the value for 0.0.